# Insert Json data in mmenu slide-out menus

Tags: html, css, json, mmenu

I am trying to figure out how to inject json data into a
contacts list using the mmenu plugin.  An example of the contacts
list is located here https://mmenujs.com/demo/index.html?demo=menu-advanced-4.  The contacts are currently hardcoded in the
html.  I want to get the contacts info from a json file.

How could I do this?

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul id="contacts">
                <li>
                    <span>
                        <span class="preview">
                            <img src="img/profile-1-b.png" />
                            <span>Alan<br>
                                <small>Thompson</small>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>

                    <div data-mm-title="Alan Thompson">
                        <div class="details">
                            <img src="img/profile-1-b.png" />
                            <strong>Alan</strong>
                            <dl>
                                <dt>Name</dt>
                                <dd>Alan Thompson</dd>

                                <dt>Phone</dt>
                                <dd>012-345-6789</dd>

                                <dt>Email</dt>
                                <dd>alan@domain.com</dd>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                        <span class="preview">
                            <img src="img/profile-2-b.png" />
                            <span>Anne<br>
                                <small>Cook</small>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>

                    <div data-mm-title="Anne Cook">
                        <div class="details">
                            <img src="img/profile-2-b.png" />
                            <strong>Anne</strong>
                            <dl>
                                <dt>Name</dt>
                                <dd>Anne Cook</dd>

                                <dt>Phone</dt>
                                <dd>012-345-6789</dd>

                                <dt>Email</dt>
                                <dd>anne@domain.com</dd>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<script src="http://localhost:8383/CCDir/mmenu.js"></script>

> Blockquote
```